# Extjs Bind TreePanel static data to FormPanel

Tags: data-binding, forms, extjs

This may be obvious but I can't figure out how to bind a static json object to to a FormPanel in extjs. I am new to ExtJs so I'm still learning. I have a TreePanel with various additional attributes contained on the node.attributes object. When a node is clicked id like to display the data in a form. Below is what I have. The data does not get bound to the fields.

All the examples for extjs cover loading data from a store or a url.

```
tree.on('click', function (n) {

            var detailEl = details.body;

            if (n.attributes.iconCls == 'page') {

                detailEl.hide();
                var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
                    frame: true,
                    renderTo: detailEl,
                    title: 'Page Details',
                    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
                    width: 350,
                    defaults: { width: 230 },
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    data: n.attributes,
                    items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Title',
                        name: 'title',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Url',
                        name: 'url',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Live',
                        name: 'islive',
                        xtype: 'checkbox'
                    }
                ],
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'Save'
                    }]
                });


                detailEl.slideIn('l', { stopFx: true, duration: .2 });
            }

        });
```

Also is it best practise to create a new FormPanel each time or to rebind the existing formPanel?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice is to have the form rendered once and change the values according to the nodes selected.

As already mentioned, `data` isn't the field to use. To assign values in a bulk manner, you should use `Ext.form.BasicForm.setValues( Array/Object values )` method. You are getting `BasicForm` object using FormPanel's `getForm()` method.

Summarizing,

```
var form = new Ext.FormPanel({/*...*/});
tree.on('click', function (node){
    form.getForm().setValues(node.attributes);
});
```

Pay attention, that form fields' names and attributes' names should correspond.

Comment: Thanks. After looking at BasicForm and FormPanel docs for what seems like hours, How did I miss the setValues method!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the `data` configuration key does what you think it does.

Try setting values individually in the field definitions.